# Remove an addon from a Multi-Vlan using Rest Api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any way to remove an add-on from a multi-vlan using the Softlayer rest apis?. If so please tell me what should the request body be. I know that it can be done from the control portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an add-on from Multi-Vlan you can use the following rest api:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/[billingItemId]/cancelItem
```

Body: Json

```
{
  "parameters":[
    true,
    true,
    "reason",
    "customerNote"
  ]
}
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem/

To get the billing Items Ids use this rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/[networkVlanFirewallId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem.activeChildren[categoryCode,id,description]]
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall/getObject/

You will get a response like bellow example:

```
{
    "administrativeBypassFlag": "",
    "customerManagedFlag": true,
    "id": 11111,
    "billingItem": {
        "categoryCode": "firewall_appliance",
        "description": "FortiGate Security Appliance",
        "id": 33333333,
        "laborFee": "0",
        "laborFeeTaxRate": "0",     
        "modifyDate": "2018-06-13T06:24:57-06:00",
        "nextBillDate": "2018-07-03T23:00:00-06:00",
        "recurringFeeTaxRate": "0",
        "recurringMonths": 1
        "activeChildren": [
            {
                "categoryCode": "bandwidth",
                "description": "20000 GB Bandwidth",
                "id": 39999999
            },
            {
                "categoryCode": "firewall_appliance_ha_pair",
                "description": "FortiGate Firewall Appliance HA Option",
                "id": 32222222
            },
            {
                "categoryCode": "firewall_appliance_addon_bundle",
                "description": "FortiGate Security Appliance - Add-on bundle (NGFW, Web, AV) (High Availability)",
                "id": 333333333
            },
            {
                "categoryCode": "firewall_appliance_addon_antivirus",
                "description": "FortiGate Security Appliance - AV Add-on (High Availability)",
                "id": 344444444
            },
            {
                "categoryCode": "firewall_appliance_addon_next_gen_service",
                "description": "FortiGate Security Appliance - NGFW Add-on (High Availability)",
                "id": 311111111
            },
            {
                "categoryCode": "firewall_appliance_addon_web_filter",
                "description": "FortiGate Security Appliance - Web Filtering Add-on (High Availability)",
                "id": 355555555
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you want to remove all Add-on Configuration use the billingItem id. To remove one by one use the last four “activeChildren” Ids options, they are in the same order as in the portal control.

[image]